# What will happen if I execute mysql <dbname> > filename.sql

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

Just like the title, I was about to create a database dump but instead of running "mysqldump", I ran:

```
mysql <dbname> > filename.sql
```

then I realized that I used the wrong command, so I CTRL+C to kill the process.
Is there any concerns about this operation? Like will my database be erased or some severe things?

Comment: If you're worried about things like this, be very careful and always test what you're going to do on a test database before "doing it live".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to worry `mysql dbname > filename.sql` will do nothing.

The operator `> filename`is used for writing something to `filename`, It wouldn't affect your existing DB in anyway.

Comment: More specifically, `> filename` means "redirect output to the file named `filename`. Unless you execute any commands, nothing will happen.

Comment: So in general, that command was redirecting the output of the command `mysql dbname` to the file `filename.sql`. And `mysql dbname` command is just trying to open mysql shell

Comment: Yes, But you should understand various operators and there behavior before using them

Comment: @tadman Please see my comments above. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @AbdulManaf yes, I use `mysqldump` before regularly. This time I don't know what happened I just typed in `mysql`

Comment: @AlanWu What normally happens when you type `mysql`?

Comment: So using `^C` on that just stops it, right? `> filename` doesn't affect what the program does, only where it reports output.